# Prestashop Order Status Message

Tags: prestashop

I want to show a special message on the order history page based on the order status. But I couldn't find their shortcode. For example, if the order placed is "preparing", I want to show the message that your order is being prepared on the order history page. I want it not to write anything if it is on the way or is delivered or canceled. How can I get the order status in tpl file?

I try

```
    {if $orders.detail.preparing}
    <p>your order preparing click here to view live cam</p>
```

### {else}

```
    {/if}
```

but this code not working. I want order status short code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are in the **history.tpl** theme template file,
you will usually find the

```
{$order.history.current.ostate_name}
```

variable inside the **$orders** foreach loop that represents the full current order state name, you can perform a check against it to display your message.